# Why am I getting this error while installing oh my zsh on my wsl?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

**ERROR:**

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 130799 ms: Connection timed out
```

I have installed all the requirements needed for oh my zsh to run. I am using a wsl Ubuntu 22 lts and I also have git installed.
Please help me out folks, searched everywhere for the solution but nothing seems to be working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is a WSL problem, check this github discussion. I gave up using WSL after similar problems after updates, now i use a native Ubuntu.

[WSL2 HTTPS Connections Timeout](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6416)